# LINQ to XML to find a specific category in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<table name="transactions">
    <row>
        <col name="id">1</col>
        <col name="amount">2673.9</col>
        <col name="created_date">2014-10-19</col>
        <col name="display_date">2014-04-22</col>
        <col name="cat_id">13</col>
        <col name="note">Initial Balance</col>
        //other col tags
    </row>
    <row>
        ...
    </row>
</table>
```

I need to find all rows with a specific cat_id. How would the LINQ query look like? I tried

```
IEnumerable<XElement> rows = 
    from el in root.Elements("row")
    where (string)el.Element("col").Attribute("name") == "cat_id"
    select el;
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: I think the answer by psubsee2003 below does the trick. If you want to learn more about Linq I would recommend playing around with LinqPad https://www.linqpad.net/ it comes with loads of working examples like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to understand how to write a LINQ query.

If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx), you would know that the `Element()` method returns the first matching element, in this case, `<col name="id">1</col>` line is returned. Since that the attribute named "name" in the first matching element does not have a value of "cat_id", it moves on to the next `row` element.

Your query could work if "cat_id" was assured to be the first matching element every time.

If you can't be sure or can't make the change you first need to search **all** attributes for one named "cat_id", then look for one with a specific value.

Firstly, to get all child elements, you need to use the [`Elements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.  Then you need to look for a specific attribute name and value.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from el in xdocument.Root.Elements("row")
                             from col in el.Elements("col")
                             where (string)col.Attribute("name") == "cat_id"
                             where col.Value =="13"
                             select el;
```

This query will return all rows that have a `col` element with an attribute called `name` and a value of `cat_id`.  And then only if the element with the cat_id attribute has a value of 13.

Comment: This query is nicer than the one I suggested :-)

Comment: Thank you for this! I think I understand most of it, but not the first line: from el in root.Root.Elements("row"). what does the root.Root do?

Comment: Oh I think it's a typo. I removed the second Root and it worked fine

Comment: @Edwin it's not necessarily a typo, just depends on what `root` is.  I'm going to change it to an xdoc to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming root is your `XElement` "table" your where clause selects the first `XElement` "col" in each "row". The attribute for the for "col" element is "id" which is never equal to "cat_id".

What you want to do is this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XElement root = xmlDoc.Element("table");
Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> s1 = root.Elements("row")
                                            .GroupBy(ks => ks.Elements("col").Single(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "cat_id").Value)
                                            .ToDictionary(ks => ks.Key, es => es.ToList());
```

which gives you a dictionary with the cat_ids as key and a list of `XElement` rows for each key

In this example I don't take into account cols that have no name attribute and rows with missing cat_id - this would give you `NullReferenceException`s that you would need to handle in the query expression